# How to run .php file on windows hosting server

Tags: php, windows, hosting

I've windows hosting and I've developed a php web application, when I'm hosting my application under root directory (web) creating new directory. When i try to access the index.php, it gives me error "bad server request" bla bla bla.

Please tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if the PHP is properly installed just upload a page with this coding and see if u get a response `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

if no response..

Please contact your hosing provider . Windows servers doesn't support php extensions  you need to change to a linux server or a upgrade

is it running in your local machine you can install php extensions using Microsoft web platform installer

[The Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

Comment: but I heared a lot we can host our php website on windows hosting server. We do not require to change our hosting in case of php. Windows hosting works well for both php and .Net

Comment: did you try running phpinfo(); ? .. just upload a page with this coding and see if u get a response  <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: It is definately an problem in your web server then, contact the service provider